# WIX Component -> FileShare

Tags: wix

I am trying to share a folder using FileShare but I am getting this error; any idea?

```
Coppying WixCommonLib
Coppying TNSORA
running Candle, candle.exe -ext WixIisExtension Product.wxs
Microsoft (R) Windows Installer Xml Compiler version 3.5.2519.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Product.wxs
Product.wxs(41) : error CNDL0005 : The Component element contains an unexpected child element 'FileShare'.
Product.wxs(44) : error CNDL0005 : The Component element contains an unexpected child element 'User'.
```

Here's the script:

```
    <Component Id="FilesShareComp" Win64="yes" Guid="801595A6-4CB0-481B-892E-C37A48954DD9">
      <FileShare Id="FilesShare" Name="MyFolder" Description="MyFolder">
        <Permission User="sharedusers" GenericAll="yes" />
      </FileShare>
      <User Id="shareduser" Name="testuser" CreateUser="No" Domain="[ComputerName]" Password="Password1" FailIfExists="no">
      </User>
    </Component>
```

Comment: Looks like the answer is given on the [mailinglist](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Component-gt-FileShare-td7580465.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<user:User Id='Everyone' Name='Everyone' CreateUser='no' FailIfExists='no' RemoveOnUninstall='no' />
<user:FileShare Id='SharedFolder' Description='Share Folder description if any' Name='ShareFolderName'>
  <user:Permission GenericRead='yes' ReadPermission='yes' Read='yes' GenericExecute='yes' User='Everyone' />
</user:FileShare>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be util: not user: ?